# Request.Files is empty when files come through as an array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing some integration with a third party form builder software that allows the form to be posted to our own server. The form data and files are then saved to a DB. The issue is when the form contains multiple file upload fields, `Request.Files` is always empty.

Using Fiddler, I can see the binary files coming through. The only thing that I can think of is that the field name contains brackets in them (because it's being sent as an array) and so the model binder can't bind it properly? The field names that are coming through are `tfa_20[0]` and `tfa_20[1]`.

Code-wise, it's pretty standard stuff:

```
var data = new Submission()
{
    ConfigurationDetailId = configDetail.Id,
    SubmitterEmail = submitterEmail,
    SubmissionData = Request.Form.AllKeys.Select(k => new SubmissionData()
    {
        FieldName = k,
        FieldValue = Request.Form[k]
    }).ToList(),
    SubmissionFiles = new List<SubmissionFile>()
};

// process any files uploaded
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (string field in Request.Files)
    {
        var uploadedFile = Request.Files[field];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
                data.SubmissionFiles.Add(GetSubmissionFile(uploadedFile, fileName));
        }
    }
}

Repository.SaveForm(data);
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpPostedFileBase in order to get posted file to your action. in case of multiple files,should be used an HttpPostedFileBase[] array.

To Enable uploading in forms, is necessary to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form tag. or if you use razor syntax change your beginForm tag to this.

View.cshtml

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("action","controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = 
  "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    }
```

---

```
 public ActionResult YourAction(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
    {
        var data = new Submission()
        {
            ConfigurationDetailId = configDetail.Id,
            SubmitterEmail = submitterEmail,
            SubmissionData = Request.Form.AllKeys.Select(k => new SubmissionData()
            {
                FieldName = k,
                FieldValue = Request.Form[k]
            }).ToList(),
            SubmissionFiles = new List<SubmissionFile>()
        };

        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                var uploadedFile = file;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
                {
                    data.SubmissionFiles.Add(GetSubmissionFile(uploadedFile, file.fileName));
                }
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately, that didn't work. `files` was null.

Comment: @SamD. could you please share your view file. Please make sure that your form supports uploading. I added additional code to enable uploading.